# Should I use "except one" or "except for one" in the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> All the articles were all about murder cases. Well, except (for) one:
>   an article about ...

Do I need the "for"? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, you can search except in [Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/except_1).

Another reference:

[OALD's entry:](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/except_1?q=except)

> except: **(also except for)** used before you mention the only thing or person about which a statement is not true